# VB .net Change text of selected textbox on button click

Tags: vb.net

I have 10 buttons and I want to click on a button so it changes text of the focused textbox and switch to next textbox.
 i tried this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Focus Then
        TextBox1.Text = "1"
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Focus()
        TextBox2.Enabled = True
    End If
    If TextBox2.Focus Then
        TextBox2.Text = "1"
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
        TextBox3.Focus()
        TextBox3.Enabled = True
    End If
    If TextBox3.Focus Then
        TextBox3.Text = "1"
        TextBox3.Enebled= False
        TextBox4.Focus()
        TextBox4.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But it writes the value in every textbox instead of just going to the next textboxt

Comment: As the documentation clearly states, an application developer should not be calling `Focus`. If you want to set focus to a control then you should call its `Select` method. Also, you generally should not need to set focus to a specific control in the `Load` event handler. If possible, you should set the Tab order of your controls such that the one you want focused by default is first. That may not be possible, depending on your layout, so you can do it explicitly in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
 If TextBox1.Focus Then
```

`Focus` is **not** a boolean property. In VB.Net, you can call methods without parentheses, and that's what you're doing here. The conditional block actually tries to **set** the focus. And since this is always gonna succeed unless you explicitly handle the event and block it, *all* of those `If` conditions result in `True`.

To find which control has focus, do this:

```
Public Shared Function FindFocusedControl(control As Control) As Control
    Dim container = TryCast(control,IContainerControl)
    While container IsNot Nothing
        control = container.ActiveControl
        container = TryCast(control, IContainerControl)
    End While
    Return control
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your `Click` event handler, you are calling the `Focus` method of each `TextBox` in turn and then populating them if it succeeds.  It will succeed every time so you populate every `TextBox`.

I suspect that what you meant to do was test the `Focused` property rather than call the `Focus` method. That would make more sense because then it would only populate the `TextBox` that had focus.  That is still flawed though, because the `Button` that you just clicked will have focus, so you won't actually populate any `TextBox`.

You have two main choices here.  Firstly, you could use a custom `Button` control that will not take focus when it is clicked.  That way, the `TextBox` that had focus when you clicked will still have focus.  Alternatively, you could remember which control last had focus by assigning it to a field and using that.  That's probably the way that I'd go.

Here's a quick (i.e. not rigorous) example of the second option:

```
Private lastActiveControl As Control

Private Sub TextBoxes_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.Leave,
                                                                      TextBox3.Leave,
                                                                      TextBox2.Leave,
                                                                      TextBox1.Leave
    lastActiveControl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim textBoxes = New Control() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4}
    Dim lastTextBoxIndex = Array.IndexOf(textBoxes, lastActiveControl)

    If lastTextBoxIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim nextTextBoxIndex = (lastTextBoxIndex + 1) Mod textBoxes.Length
        Dim nextTextBox = textBoxes(nextTextBoxIndex)

        lastActiveControl.Text = "1"
        lastActiveControl.Enabled = False
        nextTextBox.Enabled = True
        nextTextBox.Select()
    End If
End Sub
```